# How to get launcher apps in Android .NET8 for scanning?

Tags: android, maui, .net-8.0

I have a .NET8 Android app, I want to provide access points to scan QR Code/Barcode from my app. User can use any app for scanning available in Playstore. So how should I bring the launcher to select from the related (scanning) apps the user has installed?

Comment: Why can't you scan the QR code directly from your app?

Comment: So, I am migrating from Xamarin to .NET8 and the ZXing /Cognex libraries that I use currenlty are incompatible. Moving to Maui is not feasible in a short timespan. Hence app to app is one option so that customers can use their required app, so looking for showing "scanning" apps when user tries to scan from my app.

Comment: You can try to use [Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) to open the apps you want.